# c# using PostAsXmlAsync need to change content-type to text/xml

Tags: c#, content-type

I am using `PostAsXmlAsync`, which is setting the Content-Type as `application/xml`. I need this to be `text/xml`. What are my options?

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the [implementation](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http.Formatting/HttpClientExtensions.cs#L124), one can deduce that it's going to be something like:

```
myHttpClient.PostAsync(someUrl, someValue, new XmlMediaTypeFormatter(), "text/xml")
```

using the `PostAsync` extension method found in the same place as `PostAsXmlAsync`.